# If $a^5|b^3$, does $a^2|b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

I have proven that $a^5|b^3$ implies that $a\mid b$ using prime factorization and showing that every prime factor of $a$ will divide every prime factor of $b$. I have to prove or disprove that the hypothesis also implies that $a^2|b$, however, I am not sure whether I should try to prove or disprove this. I think if I knew which way to work towards, I could figure it out, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: if $a=8$ and $b=32$, then $a^5=2^{15}=32^3$, but $a^2=64$ does not divide $b$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=p^\alpha,b=p^\beta$.

We should have

$$5\alpha\le3\beta\implies2\alpha\le\beta,$$ which does not hold. (Smallest counterexample: $3,5$, with $p=2$).

Answer (score 2):

use $a=2^3$ and $b=2^5$ and you have a counterexample.